# Google Ads not showing on my home page

Tags: html, adsense

I tried with minimal ads as per the google ads publishing option, even I use single ad but still ad is not showing on my home page. I really don't know why. But it is working on my inner page as well. Even if I pass some garbage query string on my home page, it is working(like http://nypolicedispatch.com?a=b). Can any one tell me why it is behaving like this? Am I facing any coding related issue? I checked with the firebug and chrome inspect element tool but i can not see any errors related to this.

URL: http://nypolicedispatch.com/
Check the screenshots:

Home page:

[image: Without URL Parameter]

Home page with URL Parameter

[image: With URL Parameter]

Comment: I see a banner on both links.

Comment: Two banners on my home page, top and side bar. I can not see any banner ads on the home page but able to see on this link:  http://nypolicedispatch.com?a=b

Comment: Ah, I see. Or I don't. The banner is there, but it's white, while it contains 'This is a test' on the other page.

Comment: Have you checked support topics about this issue, like [this one](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/IG9u73VSjG8) and [this one](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/OutWNZS_eLs)?

Comment: Yes I checked this link and many other links also but no success. Problem is that why it is showing while I am adding some query sting but not on normal home page?

Comment: @SubhojitMukherjee Silly question: Do you have an adblocker enabled on your browser?

Comment: No @MichaelWiggin , I tried it with my IE, Chrome, FF and also remote machines with different IP's also. All are facing same issue

Comment: @SubhojitMukherjee I don't suppose you got anywhere with this? I'm having exactly the same issue with https://www.thewire.co.uk/