# Google Ad Manager adverts not showing on specific web page, but correct across rest of site

Tags: google-ad-manager

I've been running Google Ad Manager on a client's website - https://www.thewire.co.uk since 2012 without issue until July 2020 when suddenly adverts stopped appearing on the home page, though they still appear on the rest of the site. I did a deep dive into the issue at the time and could find not clear problem or solution. It's not been an issue for most of the last year, but now we need to resolve it.

What's odd is that the adverts appear if I visit the same page via a different URL, eg, https://www.thewire.co.uk/?foo=bar (query string is ignored by server) or https://www.thewire.co.uk/home/ (this is serving the same page from a different uri)

All the adverts we serve are line items we load up to Ad Manager directly - we don't use adsense. We have some in house adverts running which are set to deliver when specific slots aren't loaded, so for instance there is a leaderboard at the top of every page which should always have an advert. MPUs on the right hand column are set to collapse if no advert is picked.

When I check delivery using Ad Manager debug tool I am informed adverts are delivering correctly, and the adverts show. But in normal viewing it is not.

This is happening consistently across browsers, devices and with/without ad blockers installed, and on 'vanilla' systems running on new ISP networks across several countries, which I believe counters out any limits that may be created by cookies and IP addresses or location.

I've scoured the Google Ad Manager settings in case some form of serving block was in place, but I've found nothing, and no notifications of any limitations on our home page URL, so I'm completely stumped as to why.

I've checked the google tags and embed codes on our site and they are all OK - they are pulled from a template which is used consistently across the site, and they obviously work when I look at the same HTML via a different context, which leads me to believe the issue is some blocking in place for the specific https://www.thewire.co.uk url from Google's side.

Has anyone had any similar issue and have advise on how to resolve or able to point me to somewhere in google I can get specific support for this issue? Searches through help and the support forums have turned up nothing.

There are numerous work arounds I could apply (eg an http 301 or 302 redirect / to /home/ ) but I really want to solve the problem, not work round it only for it to arise again.

There's a previous topic on StackOverflow - [Google Ads not showing on my home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163068/google-ads-not-showing-on-my-home-page) - but that shows no resolution. So posting this maybe the same issue in case my necromancy on that doesn't work. The solutions linked in the comments on that post are either outdated or don't work.

Comment: I had a deep look and I didn't find any misconfiguration on your ad manager setup. I would now dig the following : do you need to manage de user consent in UK ? Is it a different sever side template called when you have an url parameter ? Last : the only difference I found between the 2 pages is the google analytics keep alive property active on the regular home. Could this param have an impact ?

Comment: Weird behavior : when you add native GPT eventlistenners, the slotRenderEnded event is triggered before the slotResponseReceived event on the "classic" homepage... That might explain why it always return empty / blank ads... Question is : how come this behavior only occurs on this page...

Comment: @rabsom thanks for that. I don't think user consent is a problem, as it would occur run of site, and it happens if i look via VPN from other countries. The URL parameter has no affect on the rendered template, have managed to discount that. The keep alive I've played with and made no difference. That weird behaviour I'll look into. I've had some help from A Google Ad Manager Professional and they think the url www.thewire.co.uk might have been blacklisted; thread here: https://support.google.com/admanager/thread/111155775/adverts-not-delivering-on-one-page-of-my-site?hl=en

Comment: => that would make sense (https://ismywebsitepenalized.com/thewire.co.uk)

Comment: oh, thanks @rabsom, I didn't know of that service. Most helpful. Obviously it is now a matter of just waiting for google's internal engines to churn through the issue (or redirect / to /home/ )

Comment: though having just run a whole range of sites - about 40, across education, art, fashion, music and commerce  ranging from small to medium size - through ismywebsitepenalized.com they are all flagged as penalized, so not sure how accurate that may be ;-)